# Scala mismatch while mapping Map

Tags: scala, types, compiler-errors, type-inference

I'm taking my first interesting steps (non-hello-world level) with Scala (2.9.1) and I'm stuck trying to understand a very uninformative error message.
It goes much like this:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : (Int, Array[InputEntry]) => (Int, Double)
required: (Int, Array[InputEntry]) => ?
entries.groupBy(grouper).map((k: Int, ies: Array[InputEntry]) => (k, doMyStuff(ies)))
```

As you can guess process in this snippet is supposed to be where some processing goes on, and it's actually a well defined function with signature `Array[InputEntry] => Double`.

Grouper's signature, instead, is `Array[InputEntry] => Int`.

I've tried to extract a function and replace the lambda but it was useless, and I'm stuck trying to understand the question mark in the error...

Any ideas?

**Edit:** I should clarify that InputEntry is a class I've defined, but for the sake of this example it seems to me like it's hardly relevant.

Comment: We need to see some of the code. The part of the code that was printed with the error message is not enough. In particular, what's the type signature of  `doMyStuff`, and what kind of variable are you trying to write the result to?

Comment: Are you sure the error message doesn't say `required: ((Int, List[InputEntry])) => ?`

Comment: I guess I should have made it more specific that entries is a Map. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This looks like the problem:

```
.map((k: Int, ies: Array[InputEntry]) => (k, doMyStuff(ies)))
```

You need to use a case statement to unapply the params and assign them to local variables. You also need to use {} instead of () because it is an anonymous function now.

```
entries.groupBy(grouper).map{case (k, ies) => (k, doMyStuff(ies))}
```

Here's a more simple example.

```
scala> val x = List(("a",1),("b",2))
x: List[(java.lang.String, Int)] = List((a,1), (b,2))
scala> x.map{ case (str, num) => num }
res5: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

If you don't want to use a case statement, you have to keep the tuple as a single variable.

```
scala> x.map(tuple => tuple._2)
res6: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

Comment: Whoops I'm wrong: he reported the error message wrong. Once you account for this, I should actually give a +1 instead.

Comment: The corresponding bug is marked fixed, so it should not be there in the next version : https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5067

Comment: @KenBloom: please read my comment, I actually copy-pasted the error message. 
Thanks everybody, anyway :)

Comment: +1: Like the use of case to destructure args. Better than `val (k: Int, ies: Array[InputEntry]) = tuple`